# Specific theme for checkbox

Tags: android, checkbox

I want to make check-box like this [image]

How can I implement it myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a selector xml file such as this : you have to cut this image and Save as yellow_show name and another image which you have to cut only square of this box without checkmark and Save that image as yellow_hide..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/yellow_hide" />
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@drawable/yellow_show" />
</selector>
```

save this xml file in your res\drawables\ folder. Then inside your layout file apply it to your checkBox like this:

```
<CheckBox
    android:text="Custom CheckBox"
    android:button="@drawable/checkbox_selector"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```